# I cant install a application!

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s7

I'm trying to install a 1-click root app but just the install button is broken. Cancel works, but not the install button.

Also this is the Android dialog box, not the webpage itself.

EDIT: Now I'm trying to test an app that i made but it wont let me install it...
Also I have no filter apps

Comment: The app you are trying to install can't root this phone. One-click root methods won't work in higher android version (5 > 7)

Comment: Im not using any filter apps

Answer (score 0):

Check if you activate install from other than market, also check can you reinstall any of app. Also you may use other tools like King (Kingo) root.